# Minecraft Spigot 1.13 FlowerPot plugin gives an error in console

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I´m making a plugin for a friend, he wants a plugin for weed growing.
I want that if i right click a FlowerPot with Seeds, an Oak Sapling spawns in the FlowerPot but I´m getting an error. I tried so much things to fix this error but I dont know how to do it.

```
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlace(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        //----------------------------------------------------//
        ItemStack amnesiaHaze = new ItemStack (Material.BEETROOT_SEEDS, 1);
        ItemMeta amnesiaMeta = amnesiaHaze.getItemMeta();
        amnesiaMeta.setDisplayName("§2Amnesia-Haze Seeds");
        amnesiaHaze.setItemMeta(amnesiaMeta);
        //----------------------------------------------------//


        Block block = e.getClickedBlock();
        if(e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
            if(block.getType() == Material.FLOWER_POT) {
                if(p.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().equals(amnesiaHaze)) {
                    ((FlowerPot) block.getState().getData()).setContents(new MaterialData(Material.OAK_SAPLING));
                    block.getState().update();
                    p.getInventory().getItemInHand().setAmount(p.getItemInHand().getAmount()-1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
[14:25:20] [Server thread/ERROR]: Could not pass event PlayerInteractEvent to DeniPlugin v1.0
org.bukkit.event.EventException: null
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:320) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:70) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:529) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:514) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.event.CraftEventFactory.callPlayerInteractEvent(CraftEventFactory.java:442) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.PlayerInteractManager.a(PlayerInteractManager.java:441) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1250) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.PacketPlayInUseItem.a(PacketPlayInUseItem.java:27) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.PacketPlayInUseItem.a(PacketPlayInUseItem.java:1) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils.lambda$0(PlayerConnectionUtils.java:19) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.TickTask.run(SourceFile:18) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeTask(SourceFile:144) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.IAsyncTaskHandlerReentrant.executeTask(SourceFile:23) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeNext(SourceFile:118) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.ba(MinecraftServer.java:918) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.executeNext(MinecraftServer.java:911) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.IAsyncTaskHandler.awaitTasks(SourceFile:127) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.sleepForTick(MinecraftServer.java:895) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:828) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bukkit.material.MaterialData cannot be cast to org.bukkit.material.FlowerPot**
        at de.deni.survival.weedplugin.classes.L_CreatePlant.onPlace(L_CreatePlant.java:33) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:316) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-800b93f-8160e29]
        ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The FlowerPot class has been deprecated and using the class will cause errors during runtime.

https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/328883

> The FlowerPot BlockState has been deprecated as each potted flower is now its own Material, rather than tile entity.

https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/407454

> Achievement, FlowerPot (BlockState) and NoteBlock (BlockState) classes have been removed. Plugins attempting to use these classes on 1.13.x or 1.14.x would not have worked as intended, but now they will error.

The only way to change the contents of the flower pot is to change the material of the block. So instead of doing `setContents`, you will use `setType` on the block itself to change the material to `Material.POTTED_OAK_SAPLING`.

```
block.setType(Material.POTTED_OAK_SAPLING);
```

Comment: This still gives an error :(                                                                                                                  `code`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.block.CraftBlockState cannot be cast to org.bukkit.material.FlowerPot `code`

Comment: @NavoxNetwork I updated the answer. It's not possible anymore to use the FlowerPot class to change the contents of the flower pot; there are now materials for each variant of potted plants.